# Can clojure/clojurescript compile down to webassembly?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, webassembly

Thinking about writing a game using web assembly. Is there a good way of doing that using Clojure or clojurescript?

Comment: Clojure compiles to Java byte code and ClojureScript to JavaScript. Your question is basically the same as saying 'are there any ways to use web assembly using Java or JavaScript?'.

Comment: No, not really AFAIK. Webassembly is generally targeted for LLVM.

Comment: It would make much sense to compile Clojure to WebAssembly. But the technologies to achieve this are not yet established enough. There are things like Garbage Collection and Reflection which do not exist in WebAssembly. You should look at the other answers and also [this article](https://v8.dev/blog/wasm-gc-porting). Obviously, without full Clojure language, WebAssembly makes no sense. Because ClojureScript with its limitation is already there, and good. Interestingly, [babashka](https://babashka.org/), running on GraalVM has the same limitations. So it is clear that this path makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Clojure compiles all functions to JVM bytecode.
Clojurescript to javascript.
You can't change that part.

But you can use .wasm files with clojurescript, just load it via regular js/WebAssembly.

Answer (score 0):

Clojure binaries (as Java bytecode) can be executed in Wasm via TeaVM. Here's a GitHub repo: https://github.com/fermyon/teavm-wasi.

And here is a resource page tracking JVM-based languages and how to execute them in WebAssembly: https://www.fermyon.com/wasm-languages/java